# VMware what to download for a webserver&workstation?

Tags: webserver, vmware-player

My question is two pronged.. I am trying to create a webserver on my local machine in a Virtual environment that I can roll to a production environment. My question is which version of Ubuntu should I use?
Any help would be appreciated.
Ry

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 Ubuntu version and all others are either older versions or derivatives (where the (lack of a) desktop is the difference) but all have the same core. The basic Ubuntu version is Ubuntu server (that one does not have a desktop).

In general I would advice Ubuntu server for this and a separate desktop system where you use SSH to copy files to and from the server. A desktop takes to much resources away from your webserver.